# How to make the Json_Search not case-sensitive?

Tags: mysql

I want to use the json_search function in MySQL to query data. But find the search is case-sensitive.

For example:

```
SET @j = '[{"x":"Abc"}, {"y":"bcd"}]';
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@j, 'one', 'ABC');
```

This select will return the *null*. But I need it return *"x":"Abc*" to me.

Is there any way I can make the search not case-sensitive? So I can get the result $[0].x

Comment: Related: [Get path expression of a value inside JSON data using case insensitive search using MySQL Json_search function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988706/get-path-expression-of-a-value-inside-json-data-using-case-insensitive-search-us)

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to make the JSON lower case before you search it:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(LOWER(@j), 'one', LOWER('ABC'));
```

See [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f449547bcf8f0aff7655f515ba5c8057) for variations.